# Normal vector on a plot

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Do a sketch of $f$ with the equation $f(x,y)=0$. Give in all non singular points of the curve a normal vector.

$f(x,y)=x^{3}-x-y$

How can I do this thing with normal vector? I know that singular points are when gradient of function is $0$ and I just put this equation in wolframalpha and got a plot, but I dont know should I do that on that way and what to do with normal vector?

Answer (score 1):

I do not want to spoiler too much, so take this hint: [EDIT: i spoilered in the comments]

if you have a curve $\gamma$ in the set $\left\{\left(x,y\right)|f\left(x,y\right)=0\right\}$ what can you say about $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\right)$?

(a curve is in this case a map $t\stackrel{\gamma}{\mapsto}\left(\gamma_x\left(t\right),\gamma_y\left(t\right)\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand. I calculated gradient, and there arent any singular points because it will never be $(0,0)$. But still dont know how to draw it with normal vector..

Comment: just do the calculation formally. apply the chain rule and use the definition of a tangent vector (by derivatives of curves) if you don't get it i'll spoiler, but i think you can do it.

Comment: I dont get it. I saw the formula on wikipedia, but it confuses me this t..

Comment: $\nabla f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\cdot \gamma'\left(t\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\right)=0$ since it is the derivative of a constant function. now you have everything you need to show that the gradient (when it's not zero) is orthogonal to you level set.

Comment: Can u please show that plot here? I have a lot of more examples like this to solve, but I dont know how use the information you gave me.

Comment: the gradient is the normal vector you need -.- can you calculate the gradient for a given function $f$ on your own or do you need help for partial derivatives of simple polynomials?